# Contraints on Form without a data class

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I working on a symfony 3.2 project and am adding a simple credit card form with a bit of validation. I built a similar form in a 2.7 project and used the constraints option.

```
            ->add('SecurityCode', TextType::class, array(
                 'required' => true,
                 'constraints' => array(
                      new Length(array('min' => 3)),
                      new Length(array('max' => 3))),
                 'empty_data' => null
              ))
```

When I run this in 3.2 I get a "The option 'constraints' does not exist" error. I looked at the documentation and between the 2 versions and it doesn't show any differences in usage. Am I missing something?

Adding error message...
[image]

EDIT: 
It could be how I'm calling the form. I'm not making the form in the controller so I'm making my own FormFactory.

```
        use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;

        //...

        $x = Forms::createFormFactory();

        $form = $x->create('My\Bundle\Form\CreditCardFormType');
```

And here is my FormType

```
    namespace My\Bundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

    class CreditCardFormType extends AbstractType
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {       
            $builder
                ->add('cardType', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Payment Type',
                   'choices' => array(
                                'visa' => 'visa',
                                'mastercard' => 'mastercard',
                                'discover' => 'discover'
                                ),
                    'data' => 'visa',
                    'required' => true,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'expanded' => true,
                ))
               ->add('CardNumber', TextType::class, array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'constraints' => array(
                        new Assert\CardScheme(array(
                            'schemes' => array('VISA', 'MASTERCARD', 'DISCOVER'),
                            'message' => 'The credit card number you entered is invalid.')
                            )),
                    'empty_data' => null
               ))
                ->add('SecurityCode', TextType::class, array(
                   'required' => true,
                   'constraints' => array(
                       new Length(array('min' => 3)),
                        new Length(array('max' => 3))),
                        'empty_data' => null
               ))
               ->add('ExpMonth', ChoiceType::class,array('required' => true, 'choices' => (range(0,12))))
               ->add('ExpYear', ChoiceType::class, array('required' => true,  'choices' => array(
                    Date('Y') => Date('Y'),
                    Date('Y') + 1 => Date('Y') + 1,
                    Date('Y') + 2 => Date('Y') + 2,
                    Date('Y') + 3 => Date('Y') + 3,
                    //...add more years
                ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Place Order'))
            ;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => null,
            ));
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getBlockPrefix()
        {
            return 'credit_card_form';
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show also your `createFormBuilder` section how you create the form? I think the problem is there.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking it might be something there too.

Comment: Added an EDIT #2 section --> can you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this use statement at the top of your file:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
```

Also, i think you need to write like this:

```
->add('SecurityCode', TextType::class, array(
    'required' => true,
    'constraints' => array(
        new Length( array('min' => 3, 'max' => 3) ),
    'empty_data' => null
))
```

You code had an extra closing bracket by the way --> I'm not sure if that caused a problem.

---

EDIT #2 based on feedback.

Try this in your configureOptions:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
        'CardNumber' => array(
            new Assert\CardScheme(array(
                'schemes' => array('VISA', 'MASTERCARD', 'DISCOVER'),
                'message' => 'The credit card number you entered is invalid.'))
        ),
        'SecurityCode' => array(
            new Length(array('min' => 3, 'max' => 3))
        )
    ));

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => null,
        'constraints' => $collectionConstraint
    ));
}
```

I think it's right, but double-check for me.

Comment: Yep, I have a the use statements and may have missed a closing bracket when copying to paste it here.

Comment: Yep, the error is that constraint is not a valid key for the array.

Comment: Can you try something: remove `'required' => true`. Just comment in out with `//` in front of it and see if that makes a difference. Try the same thing with `empty_data` as well.

Comment: Tried commenting out the require and empty_data. Same issue. I added the error as I see it if it helps.

Comment: I have tried it and same issue. Sorry for not replying here. But I did ask at the source and got a response. [Symfony-Github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21839). Not sure how to implement it though and still testing in my project.